# skipped 75 frames the application may be doing too much in its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

i am making an app to play a video but when i am running the app then it displays only the thumbnail of video and do not play it,in the logcat it gives error as
  "skipped 60 frames the application may be doing too much in its main thread"

my files are

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.video1;

 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.MediaController;
 import android.widget.VideoView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        

    Uri uri=Uri.parse("/sdcard/11.mp4");        
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

 </menu>
```

Comment: You can use Asynctask for this. [Check this link.](http://oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Working-with-MediaController,--VideoView-in-Android)